# Problems returning the length of the longest String among the values of input in a HashMap

Tags: java

I've written a method named q1 that takes a `HashMap<String, String>` and returns the longest String among the HashMap values.

This is the code I've written. I'm not sure why it's not working.

```
public static int q1(HashMap<String, String>name) {

    String longest = "";

    for (String key : name.keySet()) {
       if( name.size() > longest.length() )
       {
          longest = key;

       }

   }
    int sized = longest.length();
   return sized;
}
```

This is my code after I edited it:

```
public static int q1(HashMap<String ,String  >name) {

    String longest = "";

    for (String key : name.values()) {
       if(name.get(key).length() > longest.length() )
       {
          longest = key;

       }

   }
    int sized = longest.length();
   return sized;
}
```

Im still getting this error:

```
correct":false,"feedback":"(class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException)
Error while attempting to call static method q1(HashMap) on input
[{\"basically\":\"FIFTY\",\"frozen\":\"LivEr\",\"combination\":\"ColONiAl\",\"liquid\":\"deAR\",\"custody\":\"OPPortuNITY\",\"buck\":\"bLADE\",\"surprisingly\":\"STaGe\"}]\nVerify that you can call q1 from your main method without error"}
```

Comment: Why are you comparing `name.size()`?

Comment: it must be `name.get(key).length()`

Comment: Also the question said longest among the values of the input, not keys. So you need to iterate `name.values()`

Comment: Also, you don't need string (`longest`) var for this, you can simply save int length.

Comment: This is the error I get when I submit my work      "correct":false,"feedback":"(class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException) Error while attempting to call static method q1(HashMap) on input [{\"basically\":\"FIFTY\",\"frozen\":\"LivEr\",\"combination\":\"ColONiAl\",\"liquid\":\"deAR\",\"custody\":\"OPPortuNITY\",\"buck\":\"bLADE\",\"surprisingly\":\"STaGe\"}]\nVerify that you can call q1 from your main method without error"}

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the length of the key, not the value. You need to use:

```
name.get(key).length()
```

instead of

```
name.size()
```

also note that the way to get the length of a String in Java is `.length()`, not `.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

corrected code with your style shuold be:

```
public static int q1(HashMap<String ,String> name) {

    String longest = "";
    //Iterting only though values, not keys
    for (String key : name.values()) {
      if(key.length() > longest.length() )
      {
      longest = key;

      }

    }
    //return longest, no need to save in a new string.
    return longest.length();
}
```

Comment: Your code will not compile. You return `String` instead of `int`.

Comment: That is correct, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code is full of logical mistakes, see comments to your post. Here is working code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, String> input = new HashMap<>();
    input.put("", "");
    input.put("asdfa", "asdfas");
    input.put("asdfsdasdf", "asdfas");
    input.put("asasdfasdfasdfdfa", "asdfas4");
    input.put("assafasdfasdfasdfasdfdfa", "asdfasxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    input.put("asdddccfa", "asdfas");

    System.out.println(q1(input));
  }

  public static int q1(HashMap<String, String> name) {
    int maxSize = 0;

    for (String key : name.keySet()) {
      maxSize = Math.max(maxSize, name.get(key).length());
    }

    return maxSize;
  }
```

Output:

```
29
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * @Author Jack <J@ck>
 */
public class LongestStringFromHashMapValues {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> stringMap = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
            put("key1", "ss");
            put("key2", "sss");
            put("key3", "ssss");
            put("key4", "sssssssssssssssssssssssssss");
        }};

        System.out.println(getLongestStringFromMapValues(stringMap));
    }

    /**
     * Takes a HashMap<String, String> and returns the longest String among the HashMap values.
     */
    /**
     * Returns longest string from the map values.
     *
     * @param stringMap
     * @return
     */
    public static String getLongestStringFromMapValues(Map<String, String> stringMap) {

        return stringMap.values().stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
            .get();
    }
}
```

> Out: sssssssssssssssssssssssssss